# bootstrap-select - change background color

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-select

The bootstrap-select generates a DOM with a `<button>` with this classes:

```
btn dropdown-toggle btn-light
```

I can set the `btn-light` class to another background color like this:

```
.btn-light {
    background: #fff;
}
```

But I do not want change the CSS - I want change the class in the `<button>` Dom element.

How can I change the btn-light with another class?

To be clear:
I do not want to change anything in my css. I only want change the btn-light class of the automatic generated  DOM from  of the bootstrap-select plugin.

Comment: did you tried like this : `$(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("soemthing").removeClass("btn-light")` ?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you want to use the `.btn-light` class without modifying the default color value but be able to have another color?
You can do something like this. Add a class named `custom-btn` to the DOM element you set the `btn-light` class to. For example, if you previously wrote,

```
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light">
  Button
</button>
```

you can change it to,

```
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light custom-btn">
  Button
</button>
```

And in your styles you can write the following:

```
.btn-light.custom-btn{
  background: red; /*replace 'red' with whatever color you choose*/
}
```

Comment: yes, and how can I edit the generated DOM of the <button> ? This <button> class will be generated automatically from bootstrap-select. In my template I write only the <select> but not the <button> DOM.

Comment: You're not being really clear about your questions. And there's a chance you don't have adequate knowledge of css. From what I understand, you want to use the button's class on a `<select>` component.You can do so simply by saying `<select class="btn btn-light custom-btn">`. Class names can be applied to any HTML element. Also, do add a link to codepen.io or a similar site so people can reproduce the issue.

Comment: No - I know how I can set a background color to a specfic class. I do not want to change anything in my css. I only want change the btn-light class of the automatic generated <button> DOM from <select> of the bootstrap-select plugin.

Comment: You can set the button classes using the `data-style` attribute. Check this link for more reference: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#button-classes And always create a codepen.io project so people can help you